# spinner theme style affect whole page style android

Tags: android, android-layout, themes, spinner, android-spinner

I am new to android app design. I have a spinner dropdown in my xml page and applied `Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem` style.

Xml code:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="95dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
android:entries="@array/acc_type"
android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Code in manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="spinnerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem"></activity>
```

When i applied this style it affects whole page appearance. How to fix this?

Comment: Do u want to apply this theme to spinner only ?

Comment: yes. The style should apply to the spinner only.

Answer (score 0):

call this code "spiner" xml in your Drawable folder:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_76_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and this inside your Spinner:

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/spinner"
```

You need only 2 Spinner Images you can get it from here http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/

Answer (score 0):

Change ur manifest to

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="spinnerActivity"></activity>
```

remove this

```
android:theme="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView.SpinnerItem"
```

its causing the theme to apply on whole screen.

Comment: if i remove this the style not applied to the spinner dropdown. It displayed in a default button style.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't add to style properties in spinner and also no need to declare in manifest file.

Only define in xml layout and find out in java activity and play with code simple.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/DelvryCountrylist" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
```

I hope it will help you..
Cheers!!